# ValueError when using random.choices

Tags: python

I keep getting ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population.

I've tried so many different things to get this to work I keep getting a ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population

I cannot figure out why I just want weighted distribution. Any help is appreciated!

```
import random
import time
def get_random_unicode(length, w):
    try:
        get_char = unichr
    except NameError:
        get_char = chr

    # Update this to include code point ranges to be sampled
    include_ranges = [( 0x0030, 0x0039),(0x30A0,0x30FF)]

    alphabet = [
        get_char(code_point) for current_range in include_ranges
            for code_point in range(current_range[0], current_range[1] + 1)
    ]
    new_w = w
    while len(new_w) < len(alphabet):
        print(len(new_w))
        new_w = new_w + [1]
    print(len(alphabet) == len(new_w))
    print(f"weights length: {len(new_w)}\nalphabet length: {len(alphabet)}")
    return random.choices(str(alphabet), weights=new_w, k=length)
start_time = time.time()
#while (time.time() - start_time) < 5:
#    print(get_random_unicode(random.randint(1,50),[10,10]),end=" ")
print(get_random_unicode(5,[10,10]),end=" ")
```

Comment: You need to give a lot more info. What is the output of `print(f"weights length: {len(new_w)}\nalphabet length: {len(alphabet)}")`? Do you expect `new_w` to be the same length as `alphabet`? Do you understand why it has to be the same length? Don't you think that using `str(alphabet)` would add brackets and commas onto the string, thus making it longer than `alphabet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `str(alphabet)` you are serializing `alphabet` which is list of 1-char strings to something like JSON string `"['ヺ', '・', 'ー', 'ヽ', 'ヾ', 'ヿ']"` and it is way longer then length of alphabet list.

Both `list` and `str` types are `sequence`s, which `random.choices` receive without complaining. Since you already have alphabet, you don't need to convert it to string.

You probably want:

```py
    return random.choices(''.join(alphabet), weights=new_w, k=length)
```

or:

```py
    return ''.join(random.choices(alphabet), weights=new_w, k=length))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `str(alphabet)` results in a string that is much longer than `alphabet`, and yet `new_w` is only as long as `alphabet`.

For example:

```
a = 'blah123'
print(a,'len:',len(a)) # output: blah123 len: 7

b = list('blah123')
print(b,'len:',len(b)) # output: ['b', 'l', 'a', 'h', '1', '2', '3'] len: 7

c = str(b)
print(c,'len:',len(c)) # output: ['b', 'l', 'a', 'h', '1', '2', '3'] len: 35
```

Converting a list into a string includes all the brackets, quotation marks, spaces and commas. Whatever you think `str(alphabet)` is doing, I think you need to re-evaluate your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are turning list results into a string like:

```py
txt = 'hello'
print(len(txt)) # 5
# hello
# ^^^^^
# |||||
# 12345

list = list(txt)
print(len(list)) # 5
# ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
#   ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
#   |    |    |    |    |
#   1    2    3    4    5

str_again = str(list)
print(len(str_again)) # 25
# ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# |||||||||||||||||||||||||
# 123456789................
```

To prove this:

```py
print(str_again[:8])
# ['h', 'e
```